# javascript alert is not showing variable that i declare

Tags: javascript

Hey guy's i'm just the beginner in javascript programming i have wriiten some code like this

```js
first_name = prompt("Enter your first name");
last_name  =  prompt("Enter your last name");
email_id   =  prompt("Enter your Email-id");
number     =  prompt("enter your Mobile number");
alert      =  ("your details are" + " " + first_name + " " + last_name + " " email_id +" " + number);
```

i want to alert this on browser but i'm getting this error {alert is not function }
?? can you help me guy's.

Comment: Well, you're overriding `alert` with a string.

Comment: Or, he would be, if the syntax was right, which it isn't

Comment: @CertainPerformance Probably they are having a correct syntax in their real code, since the error message would be different in the case of lacking `+`.

Comment: Read the [docs on how to use `alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert). You need to call the function, not assign stuff to it.

Comment: alert('thinks' + person); use this.

Comment: This question is liable to **downvotes** because it is not useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for alerting something in JavaScript looks like the following: `alert(message);`. You can find a good documentation here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp.

For your example you should use the following code:

```
alert("your details are" + " " + first_name + " " + last_name + " " email_id +" " + number);
```

As the `alert();` function is already defined within the JavaScript language.

Comment: First of all thanku for replying ya its work here at SOF but it did not work at new tab console what should i do it again showing me the same result as alert is not the function (sound strange i know)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your alert string is incorrect. You need to make sure you are *concatenating* correctly. In the code snippet bellow I have fixed your concatenation (missing `+` in-front of `email_id`)

You are also replacing the alert function with the string you are making. So when you call `alert();` it is trying to run your string, not the function. Thus you must call your string something else such as `myAlert` and then alert that by using `alert(myAlert);`

```js
first_name = prompt("Enter your first name");
last_name  =  prompt("Enter your last name");
email_id   =  prompt("Enter your Email-id");
number     =  prompt("enter your Mobile number");
myAlert    =  "your details are " + first_name + " " + last_name + " " +email_id +" " + number;

alert(myAlert); // Alert the string stored in the variable myAlert
```

Answer (score 0):

use this way

```
first_name = prompt("Enter your first name");
last_name  =  prompt("Enter your last name");
email_id   =  prompt("Enter your Email-id");
number     =  prompt("enter your Mobile number");

alert("your details are" + " " + first_name + " " + last_name + " " email_id +" " + number);
```